# VBA Function - Update timestamp when selected cells are edited

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, timestamp, range

I'm having some issues trying to put together a VBA code that will update a timestamp every time something in the row is edited.

I need to have it run as a function so that i can select the range and use it across different sheets.

I've done some looking around but all of the codes I've found so far only related to a specific column and not a row range...

Any help will be much appreciated.

This is what I have working now using VBA but it only works when I select one cell not multiple.

```
Function MyTimestamp(Reference As Range)

If Reference.Value <> "" Then

MyTimestamp = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

Else

MyTimestamp = ""

End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I found with some more digging. It will work with a set range of cells selected and timestamp it. However it will add a base time stamp to start with and it will change anytime their is an edit to the cells you selected it to monitor.

```py
Function ModDate(Reference As Range)
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Reference

ModDate = Format(Now, "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss")

Next cell

End Function
```